# How can I insert data into a 1-n relation table in Spring Boot JPA without updating the User table?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, insert-update

### User

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;


    @Column(name = "avatar")
    private String avatar;


    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
    private String gender;


    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    private Date birthDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<UserRoom> userRooms;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myself", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Friend> myself;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "friend", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Friend> friend;

}
```

### Friend

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "friend", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"myself_id", "friend_id"})
})
public class Friend {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "myself_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User myself;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User friend;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "relationship", nullable = false)
    private Relationship relationship;


    public enum Relationship {
        NONE,
        SEND_REQUEST,
        RECEIVE_REQUEST,
        FRIEND,
        BLOCKED,
    }
}
```

### FriendServiceImpl

```java
    @Override
    public Object sendFriendRequest(JsonNode info) {
        String friendId = info.get("friendId").textValue();
        String myId = info.get("myId").textValue();

        User friendInfo = userService.findUserInformationById(friendId);
        User myInfo = userService.findUserInformationById(myId);


        System.out.println("=>>>" + friendInfo + " \n" + myInfo);
        if(friendInfo == null || myInfo == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Friend a = new Friend().builder()
                        .myself(friendInfo)
                        .friend(myInfo)
                        .relationship(Friend.Relationship.RECEIVE_REQUEST)
                        .build();
        Object yourNewRelationship = friendRepository.save(a
        );
        System.out.println("OKOKOK");
        Object myNewRelationship = friendRepository.save(
                new Friend().builder()
                        .myself(myInfo)
                        .friend(friendInfo)
                        .relationship(Friend.Relationship.SEND_REQUEST)
                        .build()
        );
        return myNewRelationship;
    }
```

### Console

[image: Console Image]

### Database

[image: Database Diagram]

I still don't understand why I just insert the Friend table but in the console it logs out the update user command. So I get the error "password is null". Can anyone help me, thank you very much

I want to only insert the Friend table without updating the User table

Answer (score 0):

I already know the problem is that the save method works both inserting on the main object and updating on the related objects

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).